# $(".floater").floatingFixed is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not very familiar with java-script/ jquery. i am creating a sliding social widget for my blog.
though i am able to place it on a exact location but it is not moving as i am scrolling the page,after some goggling and checking through firebug i am seeing following error in the firebug console.

```
$(".floater").floatingFixed is not a function
```

here is the code which i have written so far for this slider option

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function() {
                $(".floater").floatingFixed({ padding: 5 });
              });
            </script>
            <style type="text/css">
              #widgetcontainer { padding: 50px 220px; text-align: justify; }
              .floater { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #C9DBEC; position: absolute; top: 215px; left: 150px; width: 58px; padding:4px 4px 0;text-align:center }
              .post_share{-moz-border-radious:4px 4px 4px 4px;background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #C9DBEC;padding:4px 4px 0;z-index:11500}

            </style>

<div id="widgetcontainer">
    <div class="floater">
button options

</div>
```

i am unable to find out the cause of this error in firebug.Any help in this regard will be really helpful

thanks in advance

Update
here are the js file being included in the header section

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/scripts/jquery.floatingFixed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src ="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src ="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>/js/jquery.simplemodal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src ="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>/js/contact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Can you include the <head> tag from this page to ? it seems you may be missing the `.js` file for the floatingFixed method ...

Comment: Copy this file to your project https://github.com/cheald/floatingFixed/blob/master/jquery.floatingFixed.js, than include <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.floatingFixed.js"></script> and try again.

Comment: @ManseUK i have included the header section

Comment: @user702325 i think your problem is that you are referencing the jQuery core twice - once on line 1 and again on line 3 ... remove the duplicate can ensure jQuery is loaded first

Comment: @user702325 and use something like firebug to confirm that the js files are actually being loaded ...

Comment: @ManseUK that worked perfectly.You can post your answer it was due to double inclusion.sorry for my poor knowledge of js :)

Comment: @ManseUK hehe that double reference might be the issue. It is removing the plugin and renaming `$` again.

Comment: @Neal its bitten me before .....

Comment: @user702325 added that to my answer.

Comment: @user702325 answer created ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your referencing the jQuery core multiple times - the second time **after** your plugin .. this causes the `$` to be recreated

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/scripts/jquery.floatingFixed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src ="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>/js/jquery.simplemodal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src ="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>/js/contact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Removing the duplicate jQuery should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `floatingFixed` is **NOT** a native jQuery function.

You need some sort of plugin for it (whatever *it* is).

---

As per [@ManseUK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572939/manseuk)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386742/floater-floatingfixed-is-not-a-function/#comment-10352522) on the OP.

The issue can be due to jquery being included again **after** the plugin.

This causes `$` to be redefined and the plugin to be removed.

Comment: @ShaiMishali hehe so that is _it_ :-P

Comment: i have the file in my director, i have updated the post with the js files included in the header section

Comment: open your source in browser and copy the url of the js file from there and test if you can reach it